# Selenium 3.3.0 crashes FireFox 52 during driver.quit() @ Win 7 Home Premium & GeckoDriver 0.15.0

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver

Same problem as already written here:

[Selenium 3.2.0 crashes FireFox 52 during driver.quit() @ Win 7 Home Premium & GeckoDriver 0.14.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672643/selenium-3-2-0-crashes-firefox-52-during-driver-quit-win-7-home-premium-ge)

Does this problem affect all Win7 PCs, or just some?
What about Win8 and Win10 ?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a workaround for this problem.

Thanks a lot to the guys who found it - they deserve the credits:

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/517#issuecomment-286375220